# When do the intrinsic and extrinsic distances on submanifolds coincide?

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, geodesic, metric-geometry

$\newcommand{\til}{\tilde}$
$\newcommand{\GL}{\operatorname{GL}^+}$

Let $(M,g)$ be a **complete** Riemannian manifold. Let $S \subseteq M$ be a **topologically closed,** connected embedded submanifold of $M$, and let $i:S \to M$ be the inclusion map.

Let $d^{Int}_S$ be the intrinsic distance induced on $S$ by $i^*g$, and let $d^{Ext}_S$ be the extrinsic distance of $M$ restricted to $S$.

**Soft question:**

> Find necessary and sufficient conditions for $d^{Int}_S = d^{Ext}_S$.

**Some partial results:**

*Claim 1: Suppose that $S$ is topologically closed in $M$:*

> Then $d^{Int}_S = d^{Ext}_S$ **if and only if** between any two points $p,q \in S$, there is a **geodesic of $M$**, which lies completely in $S$, and is length-minimizing (among all paths in $M$) between $p$ and $q$.

A proof is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4581343/closed-submanifolds-whose-intrinsic-and-extrinsic-distances-coincide-admit-minim).

When $S$ is not closed, this does not need to hold; Look at $M=\mathbb{R}^2,S=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$.

---

*Claim 2 (easy): If $d^{Int}_S = d^{Ext}_S$, then $S$ is a **totally geodesic** submanifold of $M$.*

*This condition is not sufficient. Here is one way to see that:*

First, we need to following result:

> **Lemma 1: Nearly length minimizing paths are close to geodesics.**

Let $p,q \in M$. Then for any $\epsilon >0$ there exist a $\delta >0$ such that, if $\alpha$ is a path between $p,q$  such that $L(\alpha) < d(p,q) + \delta$ then $\alpha$ is in an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of some minimizing geodesic $\gamma$ joining $p,q$. That is, there exists a reparametrization $\alpha \circ \varphi:I \to M$ and a minimizing geodesic $\gamma:I \to M$ joining $p,q$ such that $\forall t \, \,d\big((\alpha \circ \varphi)(t),\gamma(t)\big) < \epsilon$.

A proof is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4581386/nearly-length-minimizing-paths-are-close-to-geodesics/4581387#4581387).

> **Corollary 1:**

Let $p,q \in S$, and suppose that there exists a **unique** geodesic $\gamma$ in $M$ between $p,q$ which is length minimizing among paths in $M$. If $\,\,\,\operatorname{Image}(\gamma) \cap \big(\overline S\big)^c \neq \emptyset,\,\,\,$ then $d^{Int}_S(p,q) > d^{Ext}_S(p,q)$.

> **Proof of Corollary 1:**

Let $t_0$ satisfy $\gamma(t_0) \in \big(\overline S\big)^c$. Since $\big(\overline S\big)^c$ is open, there is some metric ball $B_{\epsilon}$ with a positive radius $\epsilon$ (w.r.t $d^M$), satisfying $\gamma(t_0) \in B_{\epsilon} \subseteq \big(\overline S\big)^c$.

By Lemma 1, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that if $\alpha$ is a path between $p,q$ satisfying $L(\alpha) < d^M(p,q) + \delta$, then $\alpha$ is in $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of some minimizing geodesic joining $p,q$. By our assumption, there is only one minimizing geodesic between $p,q$ in $M$, which is $\gamma$.

Thus, there exists a reparametrization of $\alpha$, $\alpha \circ \varphi :I \to M$ such that: $\forall t \, \, d\big((\alpha \circ \varphi)(t),\gamma(t)\big) < \epsilon$. In particular, $d\big((\alpha \circ \varphi)(t_0),\gamma(t_0)\big) < \epsilon \Rightarrow (\alpha \circ \varphi)(t_0) \in B_{\epsilon} \subseteq \big(\overline S\big)^c$.

This shows that any path $\alpha$ which is $\delta$-close to being a minimizer intersects $\big(\overline S\big)^c$. Hence $d^{Int}_S(p,q) \ge d^{Ext}_S(p,q)  + \delta $

---

A nice example: $M=\mathbb{R}^{n^2},S=\GL$, the group of matrices with positive determinant. $\GL$ is open in $M$, hence totally geodesic. There exist elements in $\GL$ such that the straight segment connecting them passes through matrices with negative determinant, it follows by corollary $1$, that $d^{Int}_S > d^{Ext}_S$. (see discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492269/computing-explicitly-the-riemannian-distance-on-gl-n)).

Comment: The internal and extrinsic distances are not strongly equivalent in general; take $M = S^{1}$ and $S$ the complement of a point....