# Multiplicativity of "isometric projections" and commutation of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

Every $A \in \text{GL}_n^+(\mathbb{R})$ (an invertible matrix with positive determinant) has a unique [Polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition): $A=OP$ where $O \in \text{SO}_n$, $P$ symmetric positive definite. The orthogonal polar factor is $O(A)=A(\sqrt{A^TA})^{-1}$  and the positive factor is $P(A)=\sqrt{A^TA}$.

**Question:**

Assume $O(A)O(B)=O(AB)$. Does it imply the $P(A),P(B)$ commute?

What about the converse? Does $[P(A),P(B)]=0 \Rightarrow O(A)O(B)=O(AB)$?

(It is easy to see a sufficient condition for $O(A)O(B)=O(AB)$ is that $P(A)$ commutes with $O(B),P(B)$. This question is a step towards seeing whether this condition is necessary) .

**Motivation:**

This question has a *geometric* nature, since $O(A)$ is the [closest matrix in $\text{SO}_n$ to $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477855/distance-of-a-matrix-from-the-orthogonal-group) (w.r.t to the Frobenius norm). Thus, it reflects the "rotational part" of $A$; We can think of it as the best "isometric approximation" of $A$. If we know these two approximations for $A,B$ it is natural to compose them and to ask if we obtained in this way the best approximation to $AB$.

---

**Partial result:**

If $B > 0$ is symmetric positive definite, then $O(A)O(B)=O(AB) \iff [P(A),B]=[P(A),P(B)] =0$

**Proof:**

Let $A=O_AP_A$ be the polar decomposition of $A$. Then:

$$ O_AO_B=O_{AB} \iff O_A=O_{AB}=O_{O_AP_AB} \iff O_AP_AB= O_A\hat P$$ for some $\hat P >0$.

Thus, $ O_AO_B=O_{AB} \iff $ $P_AB > 0 \iff [P_A,B]=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fairly random computation with Mathematica suggests that the answer is no. A numerical counterexample is $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0.7\\0.2&4.9296967794602\end{pmatrix},\,\,\,\,B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0.3\\0.2&5\end{pmatrix},$$ which you can check with the commands

```
m1={{1, 0.7}, {0.2, 4.9296967794602}}; m2={{1, 0.3}, {0.2, 5}}; m3=m1.m2; {u1, w1, v1} = SingularValueDecomposition[m1]; {u2, w2, v2} = SingularValueDecomposition[m2]; {u3, w3, v3} = SingularValueDecomposition[m3]; a1=u1.Transpose[v1]; a2=u2.Transpose[v2]; a3=u3.Transpose[v3]; a1.a2-a3
p1=v1.w1.Transpose[v1]; p2=v2.w2.Transpose[v2]; p3=v3.w3.Transpose[v3]; p1.p2-p2.p1
```

(Here, m1 is A, m2 is B, m3 is AB. The polar decompositions are m1=a1.p1, m2=a2.p2, m3=a3.p3, and we check that a1.a2-a3 is zero up to precision while p1.p2-p2.p1 is non-zero.)

Comment: Thanks. So you suggest the multiplicativity of the orthogonal polar factos do not imply commutativity of the positive factors. Can you please elaborate on how you came up with this example? (I am speaking on the "experimenting with the computer approach". Have you tried different values in a loop until some condition was satisfied?)

Comment: @AsafShachar I created a pair of matrices and fixed $7$ out of $8$ entries more or less arbitrarily. Then, I found numerically the value of the eigth entry so that the condition $O(A)O(B)=O(AB)$ is satisfied, and it turned out that $P(A)P(B)\neq P(B)P(A)$ in my case. This strongly suggests that almost all pairs that satisfy $O(A)O(B)=O(AB)$ satisfy $P(A)P(B)\neq P(B)P(A)$. In other words, the subvariety generated by $P(A)P(B)-P(B)P(A)=0$ within the variety generated by $O(A)O(B)=O(AB)$ seems to have a positive codimension. Btw, you can try the same approach with your second question as well.

Comment: Thanks! Your code and comments were very helpful. I demonstrated the converse statement is also false.

Answer (score 0):

heptagon showed that probably $O(A)O(B)=O(AB)$ does not imply $[P(A),P(B)]=0$.

I will show the converse is also false, i.e it is possible that $[P(A),P(B)]=0$, but $O(A)O(B) \neq O(AB)$.

We take $P(A)=P(B)=P$, i.e $A=O_AP,B=O_BP$, so $AB=O_APO_BP$.

Notice that $O(A)O(B)=O(AB)$ implies $O_APO_BP=AB=O_AO_B\tilde P$, so

$$ PO_BP = O_B\tilde P,$$ and in particular $(O_B)^{-1}PO_BP$ should be a symmetric matrix. However, there are matrices in $\operatorname{SO}$ which do not satisfy this property for some positive definite $P$.

For example, we can take

$O_B=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}& \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} & \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \end{pmatrix},\,\,\,\,P=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&3\end{pmatrix},$ ($O_B$ is a rotation by $\frac{\pi}{4}$)

Then, a calculation shows:

$$ (O_B)^{-1}PO_BP=  \begin{pmatrix}5&-\frac{3}{2}\\-1&\frac{15}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$

which is not symmetric.