# Proof that argmin over Frobenius norm has to do with singular value decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Assume $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$. Then define $X = UV^{T}$, where from the singular value decomposition of $A$, $A = U\Sigma V^{T}$. In a lecture, we were told (without proof) that

$$X = \arg\min_{B^{T}B = I_n}|| A-B ||_{F},$$

where $||.||$ is the Frobenius norm.

Where can I find the proof of this?

Comment: Did you mean to say that $A \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as (or is at least equivalent to) the [orthogonal Procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem). One proof is given on the linked Wikipedia page. Another (essentially equivalent) proof is given on [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1478430/81360).

Comment: Can it be that there is an error in the MSE post that you are referencing? Because the map $\varphi$ should take orthogonal matrices (*i.e.* $X$ in the notation of the author) as input, not general matrices, correct?

Comment: So I would have said that it should read $\varphi: \mathcal O\left( n\right) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ instead.

Comment: No, there is no error there. The map $\varphi$ is defined for arbitrary matrix inputs, but for the purposes of the proof we only care about what happens when $X$ is orthogonal.